# How to plot a learning curve for a keras experiment?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cross-validation, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm training an RNN using keras and would like to see how the validation accuracy changes with the data set size. Keras has a list called `val_acc` in its history object which gets appended after every epoch with the respective validation set accuracy ([link to the post in google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/_d52pVCR_gg)). I want to get the average of `val_acc` for the number of epochs run and plot that against the respective data set size.

**Question:** How can I retrieve the elements in the `val_acc` list and perform an operation like `numpy.mean(val_acc)`?

---

**EDIT:** As @runDOSrun said, getting the mean of the `val_acc`s doesn't make sense. Let me focus on getting the final `val_acc`.

I tried what's been suggested by @nemo but no luck. Here's what I got when I print

`model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 512, nb_epoch = 5, validation_split = 0.05).__dict__`

output:

```
{'model': <keras.models.Sequential object at 0x000000001F752A90>, 'params': {'verbose': 1, 'nb_epoch': 5, 'batch_size': 512, 'metrics': ['loss', 'val_loss'], 'nb_sample': 1710, 'do_validation': True}, 'epoch': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'history': {'loss': [0.96936064512408959, 0.66933631673890948, 0.63404161288724303, 0.62268789783555867, 0.60833334699708819], 'val_loss': [0.84040999412536621, 0.75676006078720093, 0.73714292049407959, 0.71032363176345825, 0.71341043710708618]}}
```

It turns out there's no list as `val_acc` in my history dictionary.

**Question:** How to include `val_acc` in to the `history` dictionary?

Answer (score 7):

To get accuracy values, you need to request that they are calculated during `fit`, because accuracy is not an objective function, but a (common) metric. Sometimes calculating accuracy does not make sense, so it is not enabled by default in Keras. However, it is a built-in metric, and easy to add.

To add the metric, [use `metrics=['accuracy']` parameter to `model.compile`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/).

In your example:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 512, 
          nb_epoch = 5, validation_split = 0.05)
```

You can then access validation accuracy as `history.history['val_acc']`

Comment: Shouldn't this throw an error? According to the [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential), metrics need to be specified in `model.compile()` rather than `model.fit()`.

Comment: Good catch, either I got this wrong at the time, or it has changed. I will edit now anyway to match the docs.

Answer (score 3):

The history object is created during `fit()`ting the model. See `keras/engine/training.py` for details.

You can access the history using the `history` attribute on the model: `model.history`.

After fitting the model you simply average over the attribute.

```
np.mean([v['val_acc'] for v in model.history])
```

Note that the pattern is `val_<your output name here>` for every output you specify.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @nemo, Can you have a look at my recent edit?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you find the *average* accuracy more important than the final accuracy? Depending on your initial values, your average might be quite misleading. It's easy to come up with different curves that have the same average but different interpretations.

I'd just plot the complete history of `train_acc` and `val_acc` to decide whether the RNN is performing well within the given setup. And also don't forget to have a sample size N > 1. Random initialization can have a big impact on RNNs, take at least N=10 different initializations for each setup to make sure that the different performance is actually caused by your set size and not by better/worse initializations.

Comment: thanks for making me think about it. Yes I was wrong and was just ignoring the fact that the network gets better over each epoch. In that sense, like you said, getting the final `val_acc' would suffice.