# Keras: how to record validation loss

Tags: python, keras

Note: this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664783/how-to-plot-a-learning-curve-for-a-keras-experiment), but I'm not looking for the answer. Rather, how better to find the answer myself.

How do I record loss, training accuracy, testing loss and testing accuracy, from a model, across epochs? I'd like to plot a graph that shows validation loss against each epoch.

I know that the [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/) object, which can be called in fit(), or maybe model.history has something to do with it, but examining the source and docstrings are just a wall of code to me. Numpy, for instance, typically provides a very small use case as an example of very simple implementation. And yet I know that the answer to this is just a one-liner, because this really is just a question of input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As detailed in the doc https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit, when you call `model.fit`, it returns a `callbacks.History` object. You can get loss and other metrics from it:

```
...
train_history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                    verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
loss = train_history.history['loss']
val_loss = train_history.history['val_loss']
plt.plot(loss)
plt.plot(val_loss)
plt.legend(['loss', 'val_loss'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: It is mentioned in the [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) and the [FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-record-the-training-validation-loss-accuracy-at-each-epoch)

Comment: However, there is no hint on how to perform "realtime" plots, and, to be fair, stopping by a predefined number of epochs is not exactly what many people would want, or?

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  It was far from intuitive.