# Trying to get the val_loss from training a model

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, theano

I have the following class in which I try to get a list of tuples containing the loss and validation loss per training

```
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append((logs.get('loss'), logs.get('val_loss')))
```

I initialize the LossHistory object before

```
history = LossHistory()
```

And then I pass it to the fit method on my model in the following way

```
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=200, validation_split = 0.2, callbacks = [history])
```

The problem is when I try to get `history.losses[0][1]` the value return is a noneType and it shouldn't be

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, I'm kind of stuck on this for some time.

Comment: I don't see you passing the callback to the fit method. Are you sure that's the right line?

Comment: I have passed it but forgoth to put it in the code segment, sorry for this mistake

Comment: How about printing the entire `history.losses` to see what it is?

Comment: I found a work around here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283358/keras-how-to-record-validation-loss. But I still do not understand what I'm doing wrong in the code above

Comment: @DanielMöller I've printed it in the first place and it was a list of tuples, the first elements of the list were floats, the second where NoneType

Comment: Is `val_loss` correctly spelled? Try `self.losses.append(logs)` and print it to see how exactly the logs are sent by keras. It would be none if you hadn't a validation split (or maybe if your data is small enough not to create a validation batch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is late, but may be it can help someone else.

The on_batch_end is called at the end of each batch, at this moment we don't have the val_loss.
The val_loss is calculated at the end of each epoch and not each batch.
If you want to have also the val_loss at the end of each batch you should calculate it, but be aware that it will slow down the execution.
May be you can do something like:

You should add an init to your class:

```
def __init__(self, validation_data):
    self.validation_data = validation_data
    self.val_losses = []

def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
    x, y = self.validation_data
    val_loss, val_acc = self.model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=0)
    self.val_losses.append(val_loss)
    self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
```